# Swagger multiple bodies with different model

Tags: javascript, model, swagger

Hi All I am new to swagger and stuck at one point and need help from experts.
This is what I need

I want to write a PUT method that accept two different types of bodies one at one time.

I am able to do this by making two process_models and defining my bodies bases on them like this

```
>  api.process_model('MacBased',
>     {'id' : 'MacBased',
>     'required': [ 'physicalMacAddress'],
>     'properties': {
>        'physicalMacAddress' : {
>           'type' : 'string',
>           'description' : 'Mac address.'
>       },
>       'vlan' : {
>          'type' : 'string',
>          'description' : 'vlan id '
>       }
>     }
   });
```

api.process_model('InterfaceBased',

> ```
> {'id' : 'InterfaceBased',
> 'required': [ 'interfaceName', 'hostName'],
> 'properties': {
>   'interfaceName' : {
>     'type' : 'string',
>     'description' : 'physical interface name'
>    },
>   'hostName' : {
>     'type' : 'string',
>     'description' : 'Name of machine'
>    },
>    'vlan' : {
>      'type' : 'string',
>      'description' : 'vlan id '
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> });

and then body like this

```
>  api.process_api('PUT', {
>     // general group that this api belongs to
>     'group' : "ABC",
>     'spec' : {
>       path : "/config/{name}",
>       method : "PUT",
>       notes : "",
>       produces : ["application/json"],
>       parameters : [param.path("name", "Name", "string"),
>                           {
>                           "name": "body",
>                           "description": "Mac based",
>                           "required": false,
>                           "type": "MacBased",
>                           "paramType": "body"
>                           },
>                           {
>                           "name": "body",
>                           "description": "Device based",
>                           "required": false,
>                           "type": "InterfaceBased",
>                           "paramType": "body"
>                           }]
```

Here everything is working fine and I can see two body text boxes in Swagger.
Issue is that which ever body I filled swagger tries to validate the JSON for first model that is **MacBased** so first body data went fine and when I try to post data using second body it fails on parsing.

Any idea how to parse the data with the specified model of that body?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Swagger doesn't support multiple body parameter declarations. You can have one body parameter at most.

However, Swagger does support polymorphism for models. If you had a super model with a "type" field (for example) which was mandatory and was able to set the difference between the MacBased and the InterfaceBased variants, that could work.

You can find out more information about the polymorphism here - https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#527-model-object - take special notice to the subTypes and discriminator fields.

Comment: Its all documented and looks good, but I never got it to work for me with RESTeasy + JAX-RS. Do you have any implemented examples of a resource and its supermodel and inherited models?

Comment: We don't have a sample that directly demonstrates it, but I hope the docs can help - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#apimodel.

Comment: I got it working, the missing links for me was how to get JSON deserialization to handle the polymorphism. I found out about the @JsonTypeInfo annotation which allows you to provide a discriminator value so that the polymorphism also works during the magical deserialization on the JAX RS functions that swagger does for you.

Comment: Happy to hear. Not really sure it's our job to document how Jackson handles polymorphism though.

Comment: It would have saved me days of time if there would atleast have been an example for polymorphism in the PetStore examples, or anything of sorts. Judging from the amount of unanswered questions on stackoverflow, and lack of examples/implementations I could find online, im not the only one.

Comment: Fair enough. Feel free to open a ticket on that on swagger-core and we'll look into adding it to the sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70146/discussion-between-royb-and-ron).